# Webdriver Page Source Not Changing

Tags: selenium, webdriver, salesforce-lightning

I'm using Selenium WebDriver to scrape some information from SalesForce's new Lightning UI. However whenever I click something that opens a new "tab" I'm not able to find the the elements I'm looking for anymore. These "tabs" are not real tabs just part of the site inside the actual firefox or chrome tab.

Upon further investigation I realized driver.page_source is returning the source of the old "tab" that's not in view anymore. It doesn't matter how long I wait and I've even tried making the window stop loading but the source is always frthatsom the old tab. Does anyone have any ideas? I've run out.

Below is some sample code. Where I'm entering text in the search field and hitting enter. I'm only using manual waits during testing.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"input-5\"]").click()
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/section/header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/lightning-grouped-combobox/div/div/lightning-base-combobox/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[9]").click()
time.sleep(2)
action = webdriver.ActionChains(browser)
search = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"143:0;p\"]")
action.send_keys_to_element(search, case_numbers[7])
action.send_keys_to_element(search, Keys.RETURN).perform()
time.sleep(10) #Sleep while new page opens

html = browser.page_source
time.sleep(2)
print(html)

#After page loads get part data
part_table = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"thePage:form:pBlock:pBlocksection3\"]/div[2]/table")
part_data = part_table.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code you are trying?

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the original post

Comment: A new page is opening in a new tab?

Comment: It's not a real tab. It's a tab the website creates within the web page. Though when this tab is highlighted the page URL does change.